# Opencart save file from website

Tags: php, file, opencart2.x

I am creating an add-on for opencart and need to save a file from a website into the admin panel, currently I have the file contents and trying to save into a custom location but every time I run the add on I get an error that the directory doesn't exist.

Here is my code that I am using in the controller

```
if ($this->request->server['HTTPS']) {
    $url = HTTPS_SERVER;
} else {
    $url = HTTP_SERVER;
}

$file = file_get_contents('Website Link');
$FileDir = $url."upload/";
$fileName = 'products.csv';

if (!is_dir($FileDir) or !is_writable($FileDir)) {
     if (!is_dir($FileDir)) {
         echo "No Directory"; die();
     }
     if (!is_writable($FileDir)) {
         echo "Unable to write"; die();
     }
    echo $fileDir.' - '.$url
}
```

the error that comes back is "No Directory"
I have echoed out the URL and created a directory at that location called upload and set the permissions for this directory at 777 and still getting the error.

What am I missing?

Im using opencart Version 2.1.0.2

Comment: Have you tried changing $FileDir to equal the local directory rather than URL. I am assuming the URL dir is http://xyz.web/upload/ - There will probably be some apache settings needed for this to work. So for testings sake try making $FileDir = 127.0.0.1/myfolder/upload/ or even doing the dot-slash to back out of the directories and post results here. --- I.E. change to local referenced dirs rather than through the http domain.

Comment: Tried that but it didn't work, so went with the full URL, but sorted it now realised I was in the wrong directory and the file was uploading some place else.